# How to recover data from PostgreSQL data and other dictionary files?

Tags: linux, postgresql

I have transfer PostgreSQL files from RH linux 7 server to other RH linux server 7. Without installation i able to restart the database. Directory structure is there but not the data. How to recover or get back the data?
All files and folders are kept on the same locations. All folders are as it is from the old server. Environment variables are also set.

Comment: what's the problem? please show some code that works not as expected

Comment: Based on your description, everything should work fine. Compare file sizes between your old and new server. Looks like you must have missed transferring some files.

Comment: If you want to be absolutely sure about consistency you can use pg_basebackup - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgbasebackup.html